# Access data from Tree Model item

Tags: qt, qt5

[image][image]

This is my Table View structure.

How can i browse through the Table view and get SubChild as a TreeItem element.

For Example -> Group2$Child2$SubChild.

This line should return back subchild as TreeItem*.

The Header file for the TreeModel.

```
#pragma once
#include <QAbstractItemModel>
#include <QString>
#include <QMimedata.h>
#include <Qdatastream.h>
#include "Container.h"

class TreeItem;

class TreeModel : public QAbstractItemModel
 {
    Q_OBJECT

 public:
    TreeModel( const QString &header, const Container &data, QObject *parent 
    = 0);
     ~TreeModel();

     QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override;
     QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role = 
     Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role = 
    Qt::EditRole) override;
    bool setHeaderData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
        const QVariant &value, int role = Qt::EditRole)  override;

    QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const 
    override;
    QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &parent) const override;

    bool insertRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &parent);
//  bool removeRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &parent = 
    QModelIndex()) override;
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const override;

    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const 
     override;
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;


    Container GetContainer(const QModelIndex &index);
    void SetContainer(const QModelIndex &index, Container cont);

    ////////////////////// Drag And Drop Actions ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    Qt::DropActions supportedDropActions() const override;
    Qt::DropActions supportedDragActions() const override;
    QStringList mimeTypes() const override;
    QMimeData *mimeData(const QModelIndexList &indexes) const override;
    bool dropMimeData(const QMimeData* data, Qt::DropAction action, int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent);
    void setupModelData(const QStringList &lines, TreeItem *parent);
    void removeItem(TreeItem *item);
    TreeItem *getItem(const QModelIndex &index) const;
    TreeItem *getRoot();


   private:

   TreeItem *rootItem;

 };
```

I would be happy to post any specific code required.

Comment: Let's first get this question into a state where we are able to help you: Please explain what you mean by 'browse through the Table view', and to which user event your view should react, where the '$' dollar signs in your example (should) come from, show how the model is filled, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: I have a tree model where each item holds data as a class object , i want to write a function where i should be able to manipulate the data inside the Object that is the item holds.

Comment: This is a rendering application where when user draws a geometry it would be added to the tree view holding the data as a object.

Comment: I have added the GUI view , user will click on the geom  button  and add it to the Tree View , than i will loop through the Tree View and draw the geometry in opengl.

Comment: Why do you want to loop 'through the view' and not loop through your model?

Comment: Sorry basically i meant was to loop through the model.